# Extracting a line of text using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have two numbers (NUM1; NUM2) I am trying to extract across webpages that have the same format:

```
<div style="margin-left:0.5em;">  
  <div style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
    NUM1 and NUM2 are always followed by the same text across webpages
  </div>
```

I am thinking that regex might be the way to go for these particular fields. Here's my attempt (borrowed from various sources):

```
def nums(self):
    nums_regex = re.compile(r'\d+ and \d+ are always followed by the same text across webpages')
    nums_match = nums_regex.search(self)
    nums_text = nums_match.group(0)
    digits = [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\d+', nums_text)]
    return digits
```

By itself, outside of a function, this code works when specifying the actual source of the text (e.g., `nums_regex.search(text)`). However, I am modifying another person's code and I myself have never really worked with classes or functions before. Here's an example of their code:

```
@property
def title(self):
    tag = self.soup.find('span', class_='summary')
    title = unicode(tag.string)
    return title.strip()
```

As you might have guessed, my code isn't working. I get the error:

```
nums_match = nums_regex.search(self)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

It looks like I'm not feeding in the original text correctly, but how do I fix it?

Comment: try `nums_regex.search(self.soup.text)`

Comment: [I've heard this one before...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same regular expression pattern to find with `BeautifulSoup` by text and then to extract the desired numbers:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+) and (\d+) are always followed by the same text across webpages")

for elm in soup.find_all("div", text=pattern):
    print(pattern.search(elm.text).groups())
```

Note that, since you are *trying to match a part of text and not anything HTML structure related*, I think it's pretty much okay to just apply your regular expression to the complete document instead.

---

Complete working sample code samples below.

With `BeautifulSoup` regex/"by text" search:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<div style="margin-left:0.5em;">
  <div style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
    10 and 20 are always followed by the same text across webpages
  </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+) and (\d+) are always followed by the same text across webpages")

for elm in soup.find_all("div", text=pattern):
    print(pattern.search(elm.text).groups())
```

Regex-only search:

```
import re

data = """<div style="margin-left:0.5em;">
  <div style="margin-bottom:0.5em;">
    10 and 20 are always followed by the same text across webpages
  </div>
</div>
"""

pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+) and (\d+) are always followed by the same text across webpages")
print(pattern.findall(data))  # prints [('10', '20')]
```

Comment: The BeautifulSoup code works great by itself. I added self. to soup.findall to integrate it with the other code, but that's just led to a "()" output even though there should be numbers there.

Comment: @Matt well, it works for the input you've provided. Can you share the complete HTML you are parsing and the code you currently have? Thanks.

Comment: Works! I'm not sure what I was doing wrong yesterday, but your BeautifulSoup code works when I add the self. to soup.findall today. Thanks!